# Save canvas prevoius drawing - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

In the application, with dynamic coordinates I have to draw 5 rectangles.
Here's the custom view class:

```
class RectView(context: Context) : View(context) {

private val paint = Paint()

private var left: Float = 0.0f
private var top: Float = 0.0f
private var right: Float = 0.0f
private var bottom: Float = 0.0f

init {
    paint.apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 14f
        color = Color.BLUE
    }
}

fun drawNewRect(left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
    this.left = left
    this.top = top
    this.right = right
    this.bottom = bottom

    invalidate()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    canvas?.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)
}
```

From the outside I'm calling the `drawNewRect()` function. Every time the coordinates are different.

```
val rectView = RectView(this)
    setContentView(rectView)

    for (i in 1..5) {
        rectView.drawNewRect(
            100f * i,
            100f * i,
            200f * i,
            200f * i
        )
    }
```

But the problem is, that I see only the last rectangle. I want to keep also the previously drawn rectangles. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're invalidating the whole surface calling "invalidate()", so the whole area/region is redrawn from scratch.
Inside your "RectView" You have to save all rectangles and redraw all of them on onDraw() method.

Pseudo code:

```
class RectView(context: Context) : View(context) {
    private List<Rect> mRects = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    
    fun drawNewRect(left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        mRects.add(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom));
        invalidate();
    }
    
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        for (final rect : this.mRects) canvas?.drawRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not make the whole view redraw from scratch?

Comment: Use "View.invalidate(Rect)" provinding the region/area you want to invalidate. This is useful (in your code) only if Rects NEVER overlap each others, or you could see some "holes" near them.